# Is this php script for updating a logout time in a table correct?

Tags: php, sql

I am getting server error for this script. I am assuming the SQL is not correctly syntaxed but i have tried everything I could think of and researched thoroughly. I'm sure this is just a novice, naive mistake but any advice will be appreciated.

```
function updateLogout($userID) {
    $success = false;
    //  Get current date-time in MySQL format
    $nowTimeStamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $insertLogout_SQL = "UPDATE AccessLog SET";
    $insertLogout_SQL .= " timeLogout='".$nowTimeStamp."'";
    $insertLogout_SQL .= " WHERE userID='".$userID."'";

    if (mysql_query($insertLogout_SQL)) {
        $success = true;
    } else {
        $success = $insertLogout_SQL . "<br />" . mysql_error();
    }
    return $success;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting and how are you calling the function? is the user variable set?

Comment: by the way: why not to use mysql's NOW() function for date?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thank you for all the responses and advice. I will read up about prepared staments and i didn't even realise mysql_ functions are being deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @Matt's answer:

```
function updateLogout($userID) {
    $success;
    $insertLogout_SQL = "UPDATE `AccessLog` SET `timeLogout`= NOW() WHERE userID = '$userID'";

    if (mysql_query($insertLogout_SQL))
        $success = true;
    else
        $success = $insertLogout_SQL . "<br />" . mysql_error();
    return $success;
}
```

Also, you should really be using `mysqli_query`.

Comment: If it's following up on his answer, it should be a comment to his answer.

Comment: @SomeKittens, how is he supposed to post a block of code in a comment?  ;)

Comment: Posting all that code in a comment would be quite messy, no? Also, it was my answer too... just more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to set timeLogout to `NOW()` since I have experienced discrepancies between MySQL's timestamp and PHP's timestamp, but yes, this should work.

It should also be noted that `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. Consider switching new (and even old) code to PHP's PDO or Mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1.) Instead of messing around with `date` in PHP you can insert the MySQL function `NOW()` and it will be entered at the current time.  (remember not to quote `NOW()`)

2.) If `$userID` is a number (which it probably is) then don't quote it.  To MySQL:

```
3 !== "3"
```

i.e., it doesn't do type conversion.

So, your query should look something like this:

```
UPDATE `AccessLog` SET timeLogout=NOW() WHERE userID=$userID
```

You should also check out either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  The mysql that you're currently using is [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateLogout($userID)
{
    $query = "UPDATE AccessLog SET timeLogout=NOW() WHERE userID=$userID";
    if (mysql_query($query))
    {
        return TRUE;

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

It is also a good practice that you escape the data you are passing to the database using mysql_real_escape_string()